# Find s, which solves inequality

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

Can someone help me solving the following inequality?

$$ \frac{x^s}{s+1} \geq b$$

I am looking for an $s$ which satisfies the inequality for given $b$ and $x$. The variables $b$, $s$ and $x$ can all be seen positive.

Comment: Could you please say why the question was downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite as 
$$
x^s \ge b(s+1).
$$
That's the form I'll use in the rest of my answer.

Case $1$: $$x < 1$$.

First, let's observe the obvious: if $x < 1$, then $x^s$ decreases as $s$ grows large, and increases as $s$ grows small, but only towards $1$. That is to say, for $x < 1$, we have $x^s < 1$ for all positive $s$. On the other hand, the right hand side $b(s + 1)$ is, for $s$ positive, at least $b$. If $b \ge 1$, there's no solution.

For $b < 1$; we'll pick a value of $s$ small enough that $b(1+s)$ is strictly less than $1$, in fact, is less than $\dfrac{1+b}{2}$, which is halfway between $b$ and $1$. That means 
\begin{align}
b(1+s) &\le \frac{1+b}{2} \\
(1+s) &\le \frac{1+b}{2b} \\
s &\le \frac{1+b}{2b} - 1 = \frac{1-b}{2b}.
\end{align}
Now if we can *also* pick $s$ so that the left hand side, $x^s$, is at least $\dfrac{1+b}{2}$, then from the first of these inequalities, we'll have 
$$
x^s\ge \frac{1+b}{2} \ge b(1+s)
$$
and we'll have found a solution to your inequality. But that's easy, 
for we can write
\begin{align}
x^s &\ge \frac{1+b}{2} \\
\log x^s &\ge \log \frac{1+b}{2}\\
s\log x &\ge \log \frac{1+b}{2}\\
s &\le \frac{\log \frac{1+b}{2}}{\log x}
\end{align}
where the inequality changed direction because $x < 1$, so that $\log x < 0$.

Joining these two, we find that 
$$
s = \min \left\{ \frac{\log \frac{1+b}{2}}{\log x},  \frac{1-b}{2b} \right\}
$$

is a solution in the case where $x < 1$ and $b$ is in the range where a solution is possible at all.

Case $2$: $x = 1$. We want to solve
$$
1 \ge b (s+1)
$$
so simply pick 
$$
s \le \frac{1}{b} - 1.
$$
If the right hand side is nonpositive, then no positive solution for $s$ exists; if it's positive, then it's a valid solution for $s$.

Case $3$: $x > 1$.

In this case the left hand side grows rapidly compared to the right, and just picking $s$ big enough will do the trick. As a practical matter, starting with $s = 2$ and repeatedly doubling will get you there pretty fast in practice. But let's do the estimates instead.

Start by picking $s$ to be at least $1$; then $2s \ge s+1$, so $2bs \ge b(s+1)$. That means that if we can make 
$$
x^s \ge 2bs,
$$
we'll be done. Taking logs, this means that 
we want to ensure that 
$$
s \log x \ge \log (2b) + \log s.
$$
If we pick $s$ so that 
$$
\frac{s}{2} \log x \ge \log (2b)
$$
and 
$$
\frac{s}{2} \ge \log s
$$,
then we'll be done. To ensure the first, we need only pick 
$$
s \ge \frac{2 \log (2b)}{\log x}.
$$
To ensure the second, we need only have 
$$
s \ge 2 \log s
$$ 
which is true for all $s \ge e^2$, for instance,because the right hand side is $4$, while the left hand side is $e^2 > 2.7^2 > 2^2 = 4.$

Hence, to find a solution to the inequality, we pick 
$$
s = \max \left\{e^2, \frac{2 \log (2b)}{\log x}, 1 \right\}
= \max \left\{e^2, \frac{2 \log (2b)}{\log x}\right\}
$$

And there are solutions to all three possible cases, at least in the situations where solutions are possible.

I fear in my heart that it's going to turn out that you want the set of all possible solutions rather than a number $s$ that solves the inequality, which is what your question asks. But at least I know that I've answered the question you asked, whether that was what you intended or not. :)

Answer (score 0):

The elementary functions are the functions which are obtained in a finite number of steps by performing only algebraic operations, taking exponentials and/or logarithms. Each elementary Standard function, e.g. the trigonometric functions and the hyperbolic functions and their inverses, can be represented in this form.

The left-hand side of your inequality is an elementary function. Your inequality is a transcendental inequality in $s$ because $x^s=e^{s\ln(x)}$. The left-hand side of your inequality is an algebraic function in dependence of $s$ and $e^s$. Both arguments are algebraically independent of each other. Such elementary functions cannot have an inverse that is an elementary function. Therefore you cannot solve your inequality only by transforming it by only elementary operations/functions.

But the left-hand side of your inequality is in a form that allows to apply the non-elementary transcendental Lambert W function. The equation that is contained in your inequality (that means if you consider only the equal sign in your inequality) has the solution

$$s=-\frac{LambertW\left(-\frac{\ln(x)}{bx}\right)}{\ln(x)}-1.$$

To solve the inequality (that means if you consider only the greater-than sign in your inequality), you have to consider the domain of the right-hand side of the last equation and the signs of its values.

There is also another way to solve equations or inequalities that depend on parameters: you can set the unknown and/or some of the parameters and solve for the other variables.

If you set $s=n$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}_{+}$, you get an algebraic inequality

$$x^{n}-bn-b\ge 0,$$

and you can solve it for $x$ by the usual solution methods.

If you set $s=\frac{n_1}{n_2}$, where $n_1,n_2\in\mathbb{N}_{+}$, you get an algebraic irrational inequality

$$x^{\frac{n_1}{n_2}}-b\frac{n_1}{n_2}-b\ge 0,$$

and you can solve it for $x$ by the usual solution methods also.